# Android: listen for Orientation change?

Tags: android

How would I listen for orientation change in Android? and do certain things when the user has switched to landscape?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You have a couple of choices:

- Use an [OrientationEventListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html), which has a method called [onOrientationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html#onOrientationChanged(int)).
- Use config changes:

In your Manifest, put:

```
<activity android:name=".HelloAndroid"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation">
```

And, in your Activity, override `onConfigurationChanged`:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    int newOrientation = newConfig.orientation;

    if (newOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
      // Do certain things when the user has switched to landscape.    
    }   
}
```

Here is a good [tutorial](http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/10/27/handling-orientation-change-in-android.aspx) about it.

Comment: @ferostar Do config changes report device orientation change or ui orientation change? The first one seems clear since it's using the sensor manager. I wasn't sure about the second one.

Comment: As of API level 13 and up, the manifest configChanges attribute needs to be: "orientation|screenSize".  See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called

Comment: There is another way to observe screen orientation globally, without the need for `configChanges` in Activities: `getApplicationContext().registerComponentCallbacks` and override `onConfigurationChanged` method.

Answer (score 19):

In your activity, you can override this method to listen to Orientation Change and implement your own code.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)
```

The `Configuration` Class has an int constant `ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` and `ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT`, there for you can check the newConfig like this:

super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

```
int orientation=newConfig.orientation;

switch(orientation) {

case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:

//to do something
 break;

case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:

//to do something
 break;

}
```

Comment: Huang - your suggestion works well, with one edit.  You need to add `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);` at the beginning of the method to avoid causing an exception.

Comment: yes,the super call is neccessary. in eclipse,this line will be automatically added.That's why I omitted.

Comment: Never called :S. Even if i put `android:configChanges="orientation"` in manifest

Comment: It never called. Adding this on manifest made it work : android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Answer (score 7):

As of *Android 3.2*, you also need to add "**screenSize**" in androidmanifest for specific activity

So your activity declaration in xml will become

```
<activity android:name=".ExampleActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```