# Android: start Activity always in portrait but recognize orientation change

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

I want to start a new activity/intent always in portrait orientation (even if the device is held in landscape)

If I use `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`
the Activity is locked to portrait, but I want to recognize orientational changes.

So I think I have to call `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` on the first start, when the activity is created, an need an listener to remove this restriction.

But in which methods should I do that? In the constructor , or in `onCreate()` or elsewhere???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293563/android-listen-for-orientation-change

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        System.out.println("on config change method called.");

        if(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE==newConfig.orientation)
        {

                    //Portatrate to landscape...
            System.out.println("on config change method called portraite mode.");
        }
        else if(Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT==newConfig.orientation)
        {
            //Landscape to portraite....
            System.out.println("on config change method called landscape mode.");
        }
        }
```