# Keep layout changes persistent after changing orientation in android

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

I am changing visibility of button at run time.
but when ever I am changing orientation I am getting default layout defined in XML file

So what should I do to keep the changes done in layout at runtime

Thanks...

Comment: Check it, Hope this will helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6293617/2105241

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it could work. adding the following into your AndroidManifest.xml which can prevent the activity from being restart when you change orientation.

activity ..........
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Answer (score 0):

Inside file:

**AdroidManifest.xml**

<activity .. android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />

It works for me very well. That's what I was looking for.
Now, my Changes stay alive after I changed the screen-layout-orientation.

Thank you Ksharp, very much.