# Android not detecting when device rotated

Tags: java, android, rotation

I am trying to start a new activity when an Android device is rotated, but I don;t even seem to be detecting the rotation in the emulator.

I've read the thread at [Android: listen for Orientation change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293563/android-listen-for-orientation-change#) and that all seems to amke sense, but its just not working.

In my manifest I have:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and in my `mainActivity.java` I have:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    int orientation=newConfig.orientation;

    switch(orientation) {

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:

            showMessage("landscape");
            break;

        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:

            showMessage("portrait");
            break;

    }
}
```

This obviously won't start the new Activity, but I am trying to get the orientation detection working first (`showMessage` just calls a Toast and is working elsewhere in my code, so that's not why I am not seeing anything).

When I run this in the emulator and use the rotate buttons, the emulator rotates as expected but I never see the Toast...

Where am I going wrong? (I am importing `android.content.res.Configuration` as required for the Configuration constants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onConfigurationChanged` method will not be invoked when you rotate your device, actually, nothing will be invoked because of this line:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

device is just locked in a portrait mode, remove this line, and `onConfigurationChanged` method should be invoked.

If you want to detect that device is rotated and keep `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` line you can use accelerometer sensor.

Comment: Ah.. I did wonder about that, but if I remove it will Android rotate the first Activity before it has a chance to start the second one?

Comment: @FatMonk It will happen simultaneously, first activity will be rotated and the second one will be launched at the same moment.

Comment: @VasylGlodan do you have a snippet to use the accelerometer sensor to detect rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing  this lines

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

because you are locking screen orientation in manifest and you are
also overriding on config change in activity.