# Android - onConfigurationChanged is not called when keyboard show/hidden

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I need to detect hidden key board when hidden keyboard is pressed
My source code

```
<activity
    android:name="com.teamios.info.activity.MainScreenActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyScreenTranNorman"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan" />

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I tested in samsung galaxy nexus phone android os 4.2.1, but Toast didn't show when keyboard hidden
Please help me.

Comment: try this code  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "keyboard visible 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: The problem is when keyboard show/hide then onConfigurationChanged function isn't called

Comment: I'm having this same issue on Android 4.4.4 (Cyanogenmod) for an S4 (GT-i9505G).  I have an identical phone running 5.0 (Google Play Edition) and it gets the onConfigurationChanged() call just fine.  On the 4.4.4 device, the keyboard actually connects and can type characters into my app, but the app is not informed when attachment occurs.  May be an OS bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.teamios.info.activity.MainScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyScreenTranNorman"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan" />

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "keyboard hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

And add

`<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape " > </activity>`

in menifest class.

Comment: The problem is when keyboard show/hide then onConfigurationChanged function isn't called

Comment: @wind delete this from  android:screenOrientation="landscape" from your code. And add <activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape " > </activity> in manifest class.

Comment: Thank John R, It is not work  <activity
            android:name="com.teamios.info.activity.MainScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyScreenTranNorman"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan" />

Comment: Yes, still same problem. When screen Orientation is change, onConfigurationChanged function is called but when keyboard is show/hide then not call onConfigurationChanged function .

Comment: @Jon R: This problem, onConfigurationChanged function isn't called

Comment: in menifest class what is the name you are writing for this activity?

Comment: The activity's name  is MainScreenActivity.class

Comment: write .MainScreenActivity only.

Comment: I changed it but it still same problem  <activity
            android:name=".MainScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyScreenTranNorman"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan" />

Comment: @Jon R: Do you have sample source code? Can you send to me by email (hovietlu@gmail.com)

Comment: check these links maybe you get some help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called                                                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359328/android-onconfigurationchanged-is-not-being-called-in-activity

Answer (score 0):

Did you add **android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"** in your manifest file ?

Comment: Yes, I did. In manifest i config below  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"