# How to block the screen orientation and still get orientation changes notifications

Tags: android

I want to block my application orientation to portrait, but still receive orientation changes events. So I've tried to add the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` attribute for blocking the orientation and the `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` attribute for receiving the orientation changes events in the ovverriden method `onConfigurationChanged`. Still the method doesn't get called. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm trying to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

By forcing the orientation of your activity to portrait mode, you're not able to receive orientation changes.

Comment: So there's no way you could specify a certain orientation and receive the notifications?

Comment: According to my knowledge it's not possible. Check this one post over here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called

Comment: I've read it and some say that it should work. But for me it doesn'r. Anyway, I think don't understand why bloking the orientation should block the notifications. Those are separate functions. It has no logic.

Comment: Am also not getting this one. But, I had faced same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check Manifest.xml file. It should be like as below:

```
    <activity android:name="YourActivity1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
    <activity android:name="YourActivity2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"></activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

are you sure you write this for main activity like 
< activity  android:screenOrientation="portrait"...

Comment: This is the code: <activity android:name=".ui.activities.Home" 
      android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
   <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".ui.activities.Search" /> 
  </activity>