# onConfigurationChange() is not called

Tags: android, onconfigurationchanged

I found that in my app , onConfigurationChange() is not call. In manifest I put :

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

I want that when the keyboard is hide, onConfigurationChange() to be called. Why it is not called?

The method is not called when I force keyboard to be hide?

Comment: Did you by mistake put `android:configChanges` in the application tag instead of the activity tag?

Comment: no,is in activity tag: <activity android:name=".ViewPhoto" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden">
  </activity>

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked many times, a common answer is:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" rather than
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

[From This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called)

Comment: is not called even if i put android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" . My app is always portrait, so the orientation is not change

Answer (score 0):

Hey i had the same problem as you. I don't know if it will work but i think it's worth a try. I just put `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardhidden"` in all my activities i had declared in my `AndroidManifest.xml` so i had something like this :

```
    <activity 
        android:name=".appActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation" />                     
    <activity android:name=".app1Activity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation" />
    <activity android:name=".app2Activity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation" />             
    <activity android:name=".app3Activity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation" />
```

I tried toggling a breakpoint inside the method and it worked so you might want to try that as well, you never know!

Sorry if this doesn't help!