# "keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" onConfigurationChanged not called

Tags: android, keyboard, onconfigurationchanged

manifest:

```
<activity
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustResize"
   android:name="com.sample.MainActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

While the onConfigurationChanged never called when I show or hide keyboard, rotate screen.

Who knows why?

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

by default means the application will not handle any orientation changes. Try removing this line and test again?