# SurfaceView restart video whenever changing device orientation

Tags: android, video, surfaceview

I am playing video using `SurfaceView` in Android.

Whenever I rotate the device and the screen changes it's orientation, the video starts playing from the start.

I want the video to be resumed on screen rotation.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your Manifest.xml file.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

and you can use this to set height and width etc accordingly

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
   if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //Todo      
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        // Todo
    }
}
```

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
> also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
> orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
> orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
> declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
> must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
> value. That is, you must decalare
> android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your
> application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always
> handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change
> does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or
> higher device).

(copied from : [nmr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called), citing [docs](http://web.archive.org/web/20120130201824/https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html))

Answer (score 0):

Set configChanges attribute for your activity in manifest.xml as follow:
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Answer (score 0):

For tasks such as playing videos etc.. you should consider using [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html)