# Android : How to dismiss a DialogFragment on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dismiss, orientation-changes

I would like dismiss a `DialogFragment` on orientation change.

The problem is that the `OnConfigurationChanged()` is never called.

And call :

```
this.dismiss();
```

From the `onDetach()` method, returns a null pointer exception. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding :

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    this.dismiss();
}
```

instead of *OnConfigurationChanged()*, did the trick.

Comment: Note that this also causes the DialogFragment to be dismissed whenever it goes into pause state for any reason, such as for example another Activity coming into the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

[onConfigurationChanged not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called)

Add this to your manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: I added it, but OnConfigurationChanged() is still not called. I think it is because it is a Fragment, not an Activity.

Comment: Yes, I already saw this link. My problem is specific to the DialogFragment class.

Comment: perhaps you could tie into the onConfigurationChanged() method of the activity that opens the dialog. When you show the Dialog you set a TAG, you can use this tag to find the dialog and dismiss it from the calling activity

Answer (score 0):

Using `onPause()` is wider than the configuration change, instead you'd use `onCreateView()` where the view is recreated for the new configuration; in that case `savedInstanceState` won't be null.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) dismiss();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, container, false);
}
```