# Configuration changed not called on start

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have an Activity A which is displayed in Portrait mode only, which will call an Activity B which can be displayed in Portrait or Landscape Mode.

If I open the activity B on Portrait Mode, and rotate the device, everything is displayed as expected. If I am on Activity A and rotate the device for Landscape Mode, the Activity A keeps its orientation (as expected), but the Activity B then is called and does not call **onConfigurationChanged()** (which i have my logic to display things in a different way).

In Manifest im already setting:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

How can I display everything in Landscape mode, if the app is already on Landscape Mode when calling ***onCreate()***?

Comment: do putting things in res/layout-land will help you ?

Comment: Im using only one layout

Comment: post your logic inside OnConfigurationChanged(), please

Comment: my logic onConfigurationChanged only has an IF statement to handle if Landscape or Portrait. Thats all :x

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6005624/4517450)

also `savedInstanceState` is not null if there is change in configuration so for activity B you can use the logic in

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) 
    {
        Log.v("bundle", "Restored");
    }
```

Comment: Still, OnConfigurationChanged is not being called

Comment: it seems callback is already consumed in Activity A on config change. and there is no change since you are going from landscape to landscape in Activity B.