# Layout changes after turning the emulator, but not the device

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, orientation

I need to show 2 columns in `RecyclerView` when the orientation is portrait and 4 columns when orientation is `land`. It works correct on the emulator.

[image]

It's `RecyclerView` in portrait orientation.

Turning the emulator:

[image]

As you can see, there is refresh button. And after clicking on it we see 4 columns on screen:

[image]

But when I run the project on my mobile phone, there is no refresh button and I see 2 columns in land orientation.

Here's a part of my code:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        previewImages.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
    }
    else {
        previewImages.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
    }
}
```

And I added this line to manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

So, what's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: is `onConfigurationChanged`  getting called when you rotate the device? check with debugging

Comment: check if auto-rotate is enabled on the device

Comment: try using `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` instead ans also check if auto-rotation is on :D

Comment: also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620033/onconfigurationchanged-not-getting-called) question out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you change your code block in onConfigurationChanged method like this. maybe can help.

```
new GridLayoutManager(context, 1, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```